# ADO How can pipeline parameters be set for cron triggered runs?

Tags: azure-devops, cron, yaml, azure-pipelines

I've got a pipeline that is scheduled to run with a cron job.

If a user wants to manually run this pipeline, they have the option to `TagDevelopmentReady`, which by default is unchecked (param set to false in yaml).

When the scheduled run kicks off, however, I need the `TagDevelopmentReady` to always be `true`.

Is there a condition I can use that determines if the run is scheduled or not? Or can the cron job somehow take params to pass in?

```
schedules:
  - cron: 0 5 * * 0-5
    displayName: At 5:00 UTC on all days except Saturday
    branches:
      include:
      - my_branch
    always: true

parameters:
  - name: TagDevelopmentReady
    type: boolean
    values: [true, false]
    default: 'false'

steps:
  - task: AddTag@0
    displayName: Tag Build with 'DevelopmentReady'
    condition: eq(${{ parameters.TagDevelopmentReady }}, 'true')
    inputs:
      tags: 'DevelopmentReady'
```

edit: The runs do indeed add the `Schedule` tag. So I'd need to know how to read that tag. If I figure this out I will update and mark as answered.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by checking that `variables['Build.Reason']` was equal to `Schedule`

```
  - task: AddTag@0
    displayName: Tag Build with 'DevelopmentReady'
    condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')
    inputs:
      tags: 'DevelopmentReady'
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your answer, you could use:

```
eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')
```

You could also use the following if you had multiple schedules with different purposes and needed to condition to a specific cron:

```
eq(variables['Build.CronSchedule.DisplayName'], 'Specific Schedule Display Name')
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml